# Can I use Raspbian SD card on a notebook PC?

Tags: raspbian

I know Raspbian is for RaspberryPi. I have a notebook without HDD inside, but has SD card reader.
I'm familiar with Debian, so my choice goes down to "Raspbian" or "Tails".
However, Tails has "phoning home" which user can't disable it, and the developers denied to disable it(see latest maillist for details).

Does any of you using RBian on a notebook or something non-Pi device?
If so, what's your experience? I would like to know.

Comment: There's nothing much in Raspbian that's not also in Debian that would be of any use on a normal laptop (except Mathematica, if Raspbian still ships that).  As thlngan points out, by far the most significant difference between them is they are compiled for different [architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) (or more specifically, Raspbian is only compiled for one, whereas Debian is compiled for many, including the one used on the pi, which is why Rasbian is really just that one form of Debian with some tweaks).

Comment: If you want pretty much the same user experience with the GUI, install LXDE (that's the desktop environment used by default on Raspbian) and lightdm (the display manager).  Change the wallpaper to the big Rpi logo and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Raspbian is a platform-specific minimalistic fork of Debian and includes drivers for the Raspberry Pi hardware. I doubt that it includes the drivers for any non-Raspberry hardware, therefore it will be unable to boot your netbook.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully running Raspbian on L****o notebook for years. You still need to download some drivers manually, but yes it works.

There's very little options to install OS into SD card. Looks like only Tails and Raspbian support such thing.

BTW, is this what you're talking about? Tails phones home. Such a great privacy!(sarcasm)
https://mailman.boum.org/pipermail/tails-support/2016-June/000543.html

Comment: You should give make & model of that Laptop (no need to hide the brand) and more details. After all it is a heavy claim to run the Pi specific Raspbian that is compiled for the ARM architecture on another system.

Comment: @Ghanima It looks like Lenovo has (or had) some ARM based notebooks (or netbooks, or "smartbooks").   So it would probably not be impossible on such but obviously you would have to have had to put in some more work installing it than Guesting has explained here.  Simply copying a Raspbian image to a harddrive as if it were an SD card would never work; you need some sort of conventional bootloader such as GRUB.

Comment: @goldilocks which makes it even more worthwhile to be pointed out in detail.

Comment: Especially the fact that you would have to go out and shop for such a net/notebook -- this will not be applicable to 98%+ of what is on the market, I think.  Some "chromebooks" may be ARM.  I certainly don't see this as a *rational* pursuit, but to each their own.